Psychopathy and stress immunity
Is stress immunity (complete absence of anxiety or worry and an ability to perform equally well under pressure as under no pressure) a sine qua non of psychopathy?
I'm curious about the DSM-V's AMPD "with psychopathic traits" modifier for ASPD, but other nosology is fine too.
